# CSV credential python one liner

Tags: python, shell, csv

I have a csv file like this :

```
name,username
name2,username2
etc...
```

And I need to extract each column into lists so I can create a account (admin script).
I am hoping the result would look like this :

```
NAMES=( name name2 )
MAILS=( username username2 )
LENGHT=3 # number of lines in csv files actually
```

I would like to do it in python (because I use it elsewhere in my script and would like to convert my collegues to the dark side). Exept that I am not really a python user...
Something like this would do the trick (I assume) :

```
NAMES=( $(echo "$csv" | pythonFooMagic) )
MAILS=( $(echo "$csv" | python -c "import sys,csv; pythonFooMagic2") )
LENGHT=$(echo "$csv" | pythonFooMagic3)
```

I kind of found tutos to do it accross several lines but glued together it was ugly.
There must be some cool ways to do it. Else I will resign to use sed... Any ideas?

EDIT : ok bad idea, for future reference, see the comments

Comment: Using another scripting language to produce *separate* shell variables isn't exactly efficient or straightforward. Why not just use Python for the *whole* job and forgo shell altogether?

Comment: Yep I understand that, but I am confined to bash as prerequisite. I could well use cut and tail to extract the csv but it is no fun.

Comment: Using the other tool may be not fun, but making Python run 3 times (not exactly the lightest process) for just no good reason is even worse. Either stick to standard command line tools or entirely to Python. That said...

Comment: Output of python would be to print something like this : "name name2" and for the second line "username username2".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a temporary file, like this:

```
tmpfile=$(mktemp)
# Python script produces the variables you want
pythonFooMagic < csv > $tmpfile
# Here you take the variables somehow. For example...
source $tempfile
rm $tmpfile
```